# get request show spinner while loading

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery get request like this

```
get('myfile.php', function(data) {
   alert(data);
}
```

It is working correctly but sometimes it can take a long time to process myfile.php

How can I add a spinner gif to this so that it gives the user some indication that it is loading?

Is there some sort of success function I can use to hide and show one?

Comment: `success` is the function you already use to alert the data.. and you can just show it before calling the `get`. But you could have a look at the `ajaxStart` and `ajaxStop` global ajax event handlers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, before calling the `$.get` show the loader.

After getting the results, hide it again.

```
$('.loaderDiv').show();
get('myfile.php', function(data) {
   alert(data);
   $('.loaderDiv').hide();
}
```

Or what I like to do, is change the cursor:

```
$('body').css('cursor','progress');
get('myfile.php', function(data) {
   alert(data);
   $('body').css('cursor','default');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah.. Just call your showSpinner statment like
e.g `$('.spinner').show()` right before your async request.
And then hide it in the success callback where you have your alert like this.

```
get('myfile.php', function(data) {
   $('.spinner').hide()
   alert(data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of displaying a gif, you can use an HTML/CSS spinner.
Here is an explanation to make it : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_loader.asp

You have to make that spinner hidden by default and display it before your async call (jquery `.show()` function for example).

In the success function (where you have your `alert(data);`, you hide it (jquery function `.hide()` for example)

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue, was trying to implement a loading gif, but the gif , even a 18Kb one was taking long time to load.

Finally, thanks to @Pierre-Adrien Maison's post,  used the CSS method and it worked very well:

js/jquery(snippet):

```
 $(".loader").show()
        fetch('gsxapi.php?regex=' + encodeURIComponent(regex))
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
            $("#hiddenloader").hide()
                if (data && data.length > 0) {
                    $('#result')
                        .show()
```

html:

```
<center><div class = "loader" id="hiddenloader" ></div></center>
```

css:

```
#hiddenloader{ display:none; }

 .loader {
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3; /* Light grey */
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db; /* Blue */
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```